# Anyway to modify a masterpage control from a contentpage update panel?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, master-pages

Here is what I came up with for a single-source popup modal for a web application.
I put a placeholder on the master page and the code below in a separate class. The class file receives the message and builds the modal html.

This works on full postback, but not when called from within an ajax update panel.

I know why. I just don’t know of any way around it. Any ideas?

```
 Public Class Common
  Inherits SiteMaster    

  Public Shared Sub showModalMsg(ByVal sMsg As String)

    Dim lbl As New Label
    lbl.Text = sMsg
    '(for simplicity, the building of the div to make the modal is omitted)


    Dim pageHandler = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler
    If TypeOf pageHandler Is System.Web.UI.Page Then
        Dim ph As PlaceHolder = DirectCast(pageHandler, System.Web.UI.Page).Master.FindControl("phModalDialog")
        If ph IsNot Nothing Then
            ph.Controls.Add(lbl)
        End If
    End If

 End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is what I did. I added an optional variable called 'container' that can be passed when calling the dialog within an update panel.

```
Public Shared Sub showModalMsg(ByVal sMsg As String,
                              Optional ByVal container As Control = Nothing)
```

I posted my full solution here:

[How can I use a single modal across my web application and avoid repetative html on every page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22772757/how-can-i-use-a-single-modal-across-my-web-application-and-avoid-repetative-html/22772774#22772774)